# Removing RelativeLayout.END_OF which is added programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to remove `RelativeLayout.END_OF` from a view's layout parameters which is added programmatically, but it seems that just writing `viewLayoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF)` doesn't work and I don't know why!

I'm trying to make a live preview based on options and here they are my codes.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/liveExample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/liveExampleLabel">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/iranianDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Monday, 8 Bahman 1370"
        android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Text.IranianDate"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/islamicDate_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/iranianDate"
        android:text="@string/islamic"
        android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Text.IslamicLabel"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/islamicDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8 Rajab 1436"
        android:layout_below="@id/iranianDate"
        android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Text.IslamicDate"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
private void updateLivePreviewDatesLayout(boolean isChecked) {
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams iranianDateLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) iranianDate
        .getLayoutParams();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams islamicDateLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) islamicDate
        .getLayoutParams();
if (isChecked) {
    iranianDateLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    islamicDateLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    islamicDateLayoutParams.setMarginStart(0);
    islamicDateLayoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF);
} else {
    iranianDateLayoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    islamicDateLayoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    if (displayIslamicLabel.isChecked()) {
        islamicDateLayoutParams.setMarginStart(8);
        islamicDateLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF,
                R.id.islamicDate_label);
    }
}
iranianDate.setLayoutParams(iranianDateLayoutParams);
islamicDate.setLayoutParams(islamicDateLayoutParams);
}

centerHorizontal.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        editor.putBoolean("w_centerHorizontal", isChecked).apply();
        updateLivePreviewDatesLayout(isChecked);
    }
});
```

It works for the first time (removing toEndOf layout parameter) but for the next time, it won't be removed because I added the parameter programmatically.

**UPDATE**

I need to add the `layout_toEndOf` layout parameter to the view because the default position of the view is related to another view which they should be next together and after that, the view may be positioned at the center of its layout so I should remove the `RelativeLayout.END_OF` and instead add `RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` parameter. It's good to know that these two parameters won't work together and `RelativeLayout.END_OF` is more powerful that the other parameter.

**Screenshots**

Before checking the option: The default position of the "4 Sha'ban 1436" is end of the "Islamic" label.

[image: Before checking the option]

After checking the option: the "4 Sha'ban 1436" not positioned at center because the `RelativeLayout.END_OF` parameter is not removed correctly and that's the problem!

[image: After checking the option]

Comment: What happens if you invalidate the layout?

Comment: `remove... which is added programmatically` = **don't add it**.

Comment: @Knossos I'm not sure but I think I tried that and didn't help. Please give me an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: @DerGolem I need to add it as I explained in the recent updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way to fix that. I should create a new layout parameters for each view using `new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams()`.